# Как правильно передать указатель на виджет Qt?

Tags: qt5

Мне нужно заполнить "стандартный" `treeWidget`, который я создал в Qt Designer.

Обычно хватает `ui->treeWidget`, но мне понадобилось передать `treeWidget` в другой класс `MyHandler`. Я не понимаю, как это сделать. Можете помочь?

Если буквально, то: `MyHandler handler(ui->treeWidget)`.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте класс `MyHandler`, в котором определите конструктор, принимающий указатель на виджет. Далее в классе можете с этим указателем работать как обычно.

```
class MyHandler {
  private:
    QTreeView* const view;

  public:
    explicit MyHandler(QTreeView* treeView) : view(treeView) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я правильно понимаю, что код:

```
MyHandler handler(ui->treeWidget);
```

Будет замечательно работать, 
если просто прописать в классе MyHandler:

```
class MyHandler {
  private:
    QTreeView* const view;

  public:
    explicit MyHandler(QTreeView* treeView) : view(treeView) {}
}
```